# keep maximum two instances of a certain activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, instanceof

I know we can keep only one instance by

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
```

but I need that my app can create maximum two instances of certain activity not more than that.
I am using a chained **search** feature like image below
[image]

When Instance3 of the activity1 is created i want to destroy:-

1. Instance1 of activity1
2. Instance1 of activity2

is there a way we can moderate which instances should be kept alive?

any help would be great thanks!

Comment: _"is there a way we can moderate which instances should be kept alive?"_ AFAIK not by means of `Android` API, but in general - yes, there is: write your own "controller" that keeps track of instance amount. Just don't ask How? which would be too broad unless you show some effort.

Comment: @Onik is there any alternative or relatively easier than implementing MVC?

Comment: _"is there any alternative or relatively easier than implementing MVC?"_. I didn't actually say MVC... And I'm not aware of any libraries that could help with that. Sorry.

Comment: Manage the instances in a container class that enforces the maximum size of two. When you add one and the count is more than 2, destroy the oldest one.

Comment: @AlanKrueger is it correct Only the top activity is ever alive. The backstack is conceptual.